# Mailchimp Color picker change preset colors

Tags: colors, mailchimp, picker

Is there a way to set the color presets in Mailchimp's Color picker?
The color picker on the HTML template I created comes with a set of 5 defined colors and I'd like to have control over these colors.

Comment: I'd be interested if you found a solution to this and don't mind posting it here

Comment: Unfortunately not… I ended up displaying a list of HEX-colors in a text field so that the client could copy/paste them.